# Selling anonymous aggregate Facebook data

Tags: facebook

I was hoping to monetize my app by selling facebook data that has been made anonymous by stripping any user identifiers (UID).  However, Facebook's developer user agreement specifically states:

> You will not sell any data. If you are acquired by or merge with a third party, 
>       you can continue to use user data within your application, but you cannot transfer 
>       data outside your application.

Does this apply to data that I've gotten from Facebook that has been made anonymous?  If not, can I ask the user for permission to anonymously share the data?  Would this violate Facebook's TOS as well, or should I just ask them to fill in info manually if I plan to sell it?

Also, does this clause apply to 'public' data such as gender/birthday?

Comment: yes, it applies to anonymous data "any" is the key word there - that said, just to be the devil's advocate - it would be quite hard to trace the data back to you (if you do it the right way) ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far I understand, and based on what I've been told (can't remember sources sorry!), the rule you're quoting applies only to data received from facebook.

If you wish to sell information, you have to request that information in your own app.

So for example, if you want to sell the ratio of users by their gender, you will not be able to do this using the information provided by facebook and would require a form for users to enter their gender even if you know this already thanks to facebook.

The main issue is that as part of facebook terms of use, users entering their information on facebook are told that their information is not sold. If you want to sell user information, you have to get the information yourself and inform the user of your own terms and conditions (where you would inform the user of your intentions => otherwise may be construed as trying to deceive the user).